# enum value for given arguments

Tags: java, enums

Is there any esthetic way of retrieving an enum value based on two other enum types? What I'd like to do is to get a state for two enum arguments like is following example:

```
public enum State{

ONE_STATE,
SECOND_STATE;
THIRD_STATE;

public static State getState(Direction dir, Type type) {
    if (dir.equals(Direction.LEFT) && type.equals(Type.BIG)) {
        return ONE_STATE;
    }
    else if (dir.equals(Direction.RIGHT) && type.equals(Type.SMALL)) {
        return SECOND_STATE;
    }
    else if (dir.equals(Direction.UP) && type.equals(Type.SMALL)) {
        return FIRST_STATE;
    }
    return THIRD_STATE;
}

}
```

Of course this will word but my intention is to make something clearer since number of such possibilities will grow in time.

Comment: Have a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a lookup table ? An array of rows - each row containing the 2 inputs and one output.

```
LEFT,  BIG,   ONE_STATE
RIGHT, SMALL, SECOND_STATE
```

etc. and provide a method to look up and return the default if a lookup fails.

Failing that, you could investigate [double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch)

Comment: The "Effective Java" book (Item 33) considers this solution, then explains why this is not the best.

Answer (score 0):

Enums can have fields, you could try something like:

```
public enum State {
    ONE_STATE(Direction.LEFT, Type.BIG),
    ...

    Direction d;
    Type t;

    private State(Direction d, Type t) {
        ...
    }

    public static State getState(Direction d, Type t) {
        for (State s : State.values()) {
            if (s.d == d && s.t == t) {
                return s;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I already thought about it but as stated in my example I need same enum value for two different input types in some cases

Answer (score 0):

How about putting the Direction and Type as members of the enum, something like this:

```
public enum State {

    ONE_STATE(Direction.LEFT, Type.BIG),
    SECOND_STATE(Direction.RIGHT, Type.SMALL);
    THIRD_STATE(Direction.UP, Type.SMALL);

    private Direction direction;
    private Type type;

    private State(Direction direction, Type type) {
        this.direction = direction;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public static State getState(Direction dir, Type type) {
        for (State state : values()) {
            if (state.direction == dir && state.type == type) {
                return state;
            }
        }
        return THIRD_STATE;
    }
}
```

Note that this will not work if there is more than one different combination for each enum.  In that case, you will need to use some sort of lookup table as suggested by another poster.  For example, you could use a `Map<Pair<Direction, Type>, State>`.  (Java doesn't have a `Pair<T, U>` class, but you can easily make one or find one in lots of different libraries.)

Comment: how to handle case when I need same state for two different values? like ONE_STATE(Direction.LEFT, Type.BIG), ONE_STATE(Direction.RIGHT, Type.BIG),

Comment: I answered your question while you were asking it!  You'll have to use Brian Agnew's solution in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `switch`es instead of `if`s but that won't make the code shorter. It will have the advantage of being clearer and also, depending on your IDE, you can have it gives you error when the `switch` is missing cases.

Have the enum with the most items be the outer `switch` and other the inner `switch`.

Adding fields to your `State` `enum` will work only if there's only one combination of `Direction` and `Type` that "reach" that `State`.

```
switch(dir) {
  case LEFT:
  {
    switch(type) {
      case BIG:
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested EnummMap. The "Effective Java" book (Item 33) explains why this is the best solution.

```
// Using a nested EnumMap to associate data with enum pairs
public enum Phase {
    SOLID, LIQUID, GAS;
    public enum Transition {
        MELT(SOLID, LIQUID), FREEZE(LIQUID, SOLID),
        BOIL(LIQUID, GAS), CONDENSE(GAS, LIQUID),
        SUBLIME(SOLID, GAS), DEPOSIT(GAS, SOLID);
        final Phase src;
        final Phase dst;
        Transition(Phase src, Phase dst) {
            this.src = src;
            this.dst = dst;
        }
        // Initialize the phase transition map
        private static final Map<Phase, Map<Phase,Transition>> m =
                new EnumMap<Phase, Map<Phase,Transition>>(Phase.class);
        static {
            for (Phase p : Phase.values())
                m.put(p,new EnumMap<Phase,Transition>(Phase.class));
            for (Transition trans : Transition.values())
                m.get(trans.src).put(trans.dst, trans);
        }
        public static Transition from(Phase src, Phase dst) {
            return m.get(src).get(dst);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how can I get the same enum value for two different sets of argument values

Comment: You could have an EnumMap<Direction, Map<Type, State>> as the internal nested EnumMap

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate `DIRECTION` and `TYPE` in a concrete class(say `EnumGroup`) . And create a `Hashmap` that contains key as the object of `EnumGroup` and `value` as the value of enum `State`. In this way we could save the `state` value for multiple combination of `DIRECTION` and `STATE` value . We can also have two different `EnumGroup` having same `state` value. Here is the code Demo.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
class EnumGroup 
{
    Direction direction;
    Type type;
    private EnumGroup(){}//To prevent parmeterless construction
    public EnumGroup(Direction direction , Type type)
    {
        if (direction==null || type == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException("null is not allowed");
        }
        this.direction = direction;
        this.type = type;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return direction.toString().hashCode() + type.toString().hashCode() ;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object other)
    {
        if (other == null || !(other instanceof EnumGroup))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (this == other)
        {
            return true;
        }
        EnumGroup temp = (EnumGroup)other;
        if (temp.type == this.type && temp.direction == this.direction)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
enum Direction
{
    LEFT,RIGHT,DOWN,UP,ACCROSS;
}
enum Type
{
    BIG,SMALL,MEDIUM;
}
enum State
{
    ONE_STATE,FIRST_STATE,SECOND_STATE,THIRD_STATE;
    private static final Map<EnumGroup,State> map = new HashMap<EnumGroup,State>();
    static
    {
        map.put(new EnumGroup(Direction.LEFT,Type.BIG),ONE_STATE);
        map.put(new EnumGroup(Direction.RIGHT,Type.SMALL),SECOND_STATE);
        map.put(new EnumGroup(Direction.UP,Type.SMALL),FIRST_STATE);
        /*
        .
        .
        .
        */
    }
    public static State getState(EnumGroup eGroup) 
    {
        State state = map.get(eGroup);
        return state == null ? THIRD_STATE : state;
    }
}
public class EnumValueByArgument
{
    public static void main(String st[])
    {
        ArrayList<EnumGroup> list = new ArrayList<EnumGroup>();
        for (Direction direction : Direction.values())
        {
            for (Type type : Type.values() )
            {
                list.add(new EnumGroup(direction,type));
            }
        }
        for (EnumGroup eGroup : list )
        {
            System.out.println(State.getState(eGroup));
        }
    }
}
```